# Setting Additional Properties using swagger annotations

Tags: swagger

I am trying to map attributes field below,

```java
@(ApiModelProperty @field)(dataType = "map") attributes: Map[String,String]
```

to

```
{
 "type": "object",
 "additionalProperties": {
   "type": "string"
 }
}
```

so in my auto-generated java client code I would have `Map<String,String>`

Is this possible with any version of java/scala API of Swagger ?

Comment: What version of swagger-core are you using?

Comment: I am using swagger-core v1.5

Comment: Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with `dataType = "Map[String,Foo]"` (without spaces after the comma). So your might be like:

```java
@(ApiModelProperty @field)(dataType = "Map[String,String]") 
attributes: Map[String,String]
```